# How do I change the DocumentRoot in AMPPS?

Tags: document-root, ampps

I recently installed AMPPS and I am trying to change the document root to different location without success. I even tried to do it in a folder inside the original path /Applications/AMPPS/www/test without success as well. I did restart apache after each change.

I also searched all the possible paths inside the AMPPS folder and they all seem ok, but when I point the browser to localhost I am not redirected to the "test" folder.

Maybe I am missing something.

Thank you

[image: All the paths to DocumentRoot changed]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.

I installed AMPPS on Macbookpro retina OS X Elcapitan 10.11.3

If i edit the httpd.conf with default Mac's TextEdit, Apache won't start, won't restart, won't stop, it just won't work!.

> TRY EDIT HTTPD.CONF WITH OTHER CODE EDITOR.

I used app Coda and it work as it have to, and changed Documentroot ofcouse.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could find to get round this is to create a symlink

Answer (score 0):

The editor problem in Macbook might be due to the insertion of extra characters which is making the apache not restart. Enable, special characters view in the text editor and then see if some were inserted inadvertently.